# Why does Python/how does Python know to execute the callback function after pub.publish() has been defined?

Tags: python, function, publish-subscribe, rospy

In this code a function call is written, but executed after one of its variables is defined, without throwing an error.

n/a

```
counter= 0
pub = None

def callback_receive_number_data(msg):
    global counter
    counter += msg.data
    new_msg = Int64()
    new_msg.data = counter
    pub.publish(new_msg)

sub = rospy.Subscriber('/number', Int64, callback_receive_number_data)
pub = rospy.Publisher('/number_count', Int64, queue_size=10)
```

Comment: The function always uses the value of `pub` as of the time the function is called. It doesn’t bind to the current value of `pub` when the function is defined. Instead, when the function runs, it looks up the current value of `pub` and uses that.

Comment: Please remember to use the `rospy` tag for questions about this package.

Comment: its not a question about rospy. Its a question about python variables and function call executions.

Comment: It would be helpful to convert this to a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and probably remove some tags. I think you are mainly interested in why a Python function uses the current value of a module variable when the function is called, instead of the value when the function was defined.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try a simpler piece of code with similar behavior:

```
pub = None

def func():
    return pub

pub = "thing"
func()  # returns "thing"
```

You might expect `func` to return `None`, because that's the value of `pub` when `func` is defined. But Python actually processes the code like this:

1. create a variable in the module namespace called 'pub', and assign it a value of `None`
2. create a variable in the module namespace called 'func', and make it point to a block of function code. The function code is a script to do the following:

   - find the variable called 'pub' in the module namespace
   - get the value of this variable
   - return that value
3. assign the value 'thing' to the variable called 'pub' in the module namespace
4. lookup the 'func' variable in the module namespace, and call the code that it points to.

The important thing to note here is that step 2 doesn't do anything with the current value of `pub`. It just defines a function that will (eventually) lookup `pub` and do something with its value. `pub` doesn't even need to be defined when Python gets to step 2.

When Python gets to step 4, that is when the code in `func` (defined in step 2) actually gets executed. At this point, the function looks (for the first time) for the `pub` variable in the module namespace. Then it retrieves the value and works with it. Since this happens after step 3, the function finds that `pub` has the value "thing".

I guess the key idea here is that the `def` statement just creates a function as an abstract block of code. It does not lookup the current values of module variables and attach them to the function. Instead, the function itself looks up those variables and retrieves their values when it is called later.

Comment: so func() ignores the function call until it has found the value for pub?

Comment: The code in `func()` does not do anything (including checking the existence or value of external variables) until you actually call the function. When the `def` statement defines the function, it doesn’t matter if those variables exist or not, or what value they have. `def ` just defines a function, which is ignored until you call it.

Comment: you're example is not the same as mine. in my example func() is called before pub = 'thing'. in you're example func() is called after pub = 'thing'

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. Your example uses a callback function. The function is not actually called when you create the subscriber. When you just pass the function name, not followed by parentheses, you send a reference to the function but don’t actually call it yet. Then the subscriber calls it later when it gets a message. In your example, I assume that doesn’t happen till after you create the publisher. Your code doesn’t actually reveal when the function is called. It could be in another thread, in which case you may have a race condition. Or it could be when you start an (unshown) event loop.

Comment: I don't know about threading or race conditions, but I assume the function  is instructed to be called by the Subscriber class after pub is defined. Thank you for answering my question though

Comment: Your code creates a subscriber waiting for a message on the topic '/number'.   The [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) could occur because there is a brief period after you create the subscriber, when `pub` has not been properly defined. If rospy uses a background thread to run subscriber code, then it's possible that the subscriber could receive a message during this time, then try to use the invalid `pub` and crash. (I don't know the rospy architecture well enough to say whether that's possible.) In that case, it would be safer to define `pub` before `sub`.

Comment: I could update my example code to show how callbacks work, and what happens if the callback function refers to objects that aren't defined before the function is created (hint: it doesn't matter; the object isn't looked up till the callback is called), but it seems like you have the idea now.